# Which order does spring start beans?

Tags: java, spring, initialization

I have two beans (class A and class B) defined in an XML file. When I start them, the DefaultListableBeanFactory creates the instance of class A first, then the instance of class B. Then I copy the classes into a separate package and make some minor modifications. When I start the classes from the new package, the DefaultListableBeanFactory creates the instance of class B first, then the instance of class A. Why did Spring change the initialization order? It doesn't seem to be random (i.e. in the old package always class A is started first, in the new package always class B is started first). I can (and probably should) add a "depends-on" tag to the definition of class B to ensure consistent start order, but I'd like to know why it worked in the old package.

Comment: Order of bean initialization should not matter since the fields are injected after creating the bean. The only problem where the order will matter is when the bean is needed at constructor argument of other class, but Spring notices this and will solve it.

Comment: As you say, you shouldn't depend on it. If two beans genuinely depend on each other, Spring will make sure the dependent is initialised after the dependee. Beyond that, it's anybody's guess. Maybe the fully qualified class names are put in a hash map and this is the order they are returned in.

Comment: Well, actually class B depends on a side effect from class A, but as it always worked in the old package and always works on other developers computers in the new package, nobody noticed the dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring will use a `ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner` to find all your beans and register them in a `BeanDefinitionRegistry`. Internally it will use a `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver`. The beans will be added in the order they are discovered, and later, spring will iterate over them and load them in this order resolving the needed dependencies (see `DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons`).

The idea behind Spring mechanism is to hide from you all this stuff and guarantee a well constructed object graph in your application context as soon as your definitions are correct (Spring can instantiate your bean, Spring can resolve its dependencies ...)

From `DefaultListableBeanFactory` :

```
/** List of bean definition names, in registration order */
private final List<String> beanDefinitionNames = new ArrayList<String>(64);
```